# Can one author a library API – one accessible outside Python – using Cython?

Tags: python, c++, c, api, cython

I know Cython's purpose is to create Python extensions modules, but can the compiled libraries made with Cython be loaded by non-python programs? If not, why?

Comment: Depends a lot on what features of Cython the library in question uses, I'd figure.

Comment: Why would you wanna do it in the first place?

Comment: To build libraries in Python? I'm amazed that this isn't quite common actually...

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can load them *directly* on a non-python program; looking at the C code generated by the simplest Cython script it's apparent that you need all the Python scaffolding to make it work. That said, you can do it indirectly for example from C++. In C++ I use [boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) to [embed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/exec.html) the Python interpreter and load some of my modules and scripts. This may seem convoluted, but allows you to quickly use whatever extensions you already have written in Python from C++, provided that you build the appropriate gluing code (see [the boost.python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/extract)).

The disadvantage of this approach is that you are really loading a full Python interpreter just to be able to use some extension. This wasn't an issue for me since I already had the python extension and was embedding Python in my application to provide basic scripting ability, but I would not use this approach to write new libraries.

Comment: Right, google looking for the several available utilities to embed Python in C/C++ programs. Boost is not the only one...

Answer (score 0):

There are [two mechanisms by which you can make](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c) `cdef`’ed Cython structures available externally:

1. [Use a `cdef public` declaration](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#public-declarations) – and/or also
2. [Use the `api` keyword.](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#c-api-declarations)

Here’s one of the examples of both mechanisms, from the aforelinked pages:

```cpp
cdef public struct Vehicle:
    int speed
    float power

cdef api void activate(Vehicle *v):
    if v.speed >= 88 and v.power >= 1.21:
        print "Time travel achieved"
```

Each of these methods will instruct the Cython compiler to generate a header (“.h”) file that you can then integrate with your orthogonal C/C++ project.

A `cdef public` declaration yields a file named `modulename.h`; using the structures in this file will require you to link with the compiled Cython extension module.

An `api` declaration (which may be used simultaneously with `cdef public`, if you so desire) yields a `modulename_api.h` file; code consuming an `api`-based header will not need to link to the extension module – but it *will* need to call the `cdef`’d function `import_modulename()` before any of the API code can be used (a tactic the Cython-inclined users of NumPy will [find familiar](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/9286f3d46c230d2f823728eb3ad3b2a892556e83/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd#L994-L1012)).

In my personal experience, it takes little effort to expose and subsequently employ encythoned structures as an external API in this fashion, provided that the struct layouts dovetail well with the consuming code, and that you’re willing to contend with manually managing the GIL in your C/C++ code in order to make things work.